# How to Obtain MongoDB Primary by Filtering stdout_lines in Ansible?

Tags: regex, mongodb, ansible

I have the following task in my playbook that is supposed to get the primary in a MongoDB replica set:

```
- name: get primary
  shell: mongo --host {{ mongodb_replicaset_name }}/{{ mongodb_hosts }} --quiet --eval "rs.isMaster().primary"
  register: primary_result
  changed_when: false
  run_once: true
```

The result I'm expecting should look like this at the shell:

> rs0:PRIMARY> rs.isMaster().primary
>
> mongotest1:27017

I was trying to use the following task to grab the result, but it doesn't work because the output contains all of the networking messages and the ordering is not guaranteed.

```
- name: set primary host:port string
  set_fact:
    primary: "{{ primary_result.stdout_lines[-1] }}"
  run_once: true
```

I have gotten results where the "mongotest1:27017" is in the middle of all that other informational output like this:

```
ok: [mongotest4] => {
    "primary_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "cmd": "mongo --host rs0/mongotest1,mongotest2,mongotest3,mongotest4,mongotest5 --quiet --eval \"rs.isMaster().primary\"",
        "delta": "0:00:00.073013",
        "end": "2019-05-17 19:09:57.954030",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-05-17 19:09:57.881017",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "2019-05-17T19:09:57.940+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for rs0/mongotest1:27017,mongotest2:27017,mongotest3:27017,mongotest4:27017,mongotest5:27017\n2019-05-17T19:09:57.943+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest2:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest2:27017 with a 5 second timeout)\n2019-05-17T19:09:57.944+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to mongotest1:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest1:27017 with a 5 second timeout)\n2019-05-17T19:09:57.945+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest5:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest5:27017 with a 5 second timeout)\nmongotest1:27017\n2019-05-17T19:09:57.949+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest3:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest3:27017 with a 5 second timeout)\n2019-05-17T19:09:57.951+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest4:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest4:27017 with a 5 second timeout)",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "2019-05-17T19:09:57.940+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for rs0/mongotest1:27017,mongotest2:27017,mongotest3:27017,mongotest4:27017,mongotest5:27017",
            "2019-05-17T19:09:57.943+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest2:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest2:27017 with a 5 second timeout)",
            "2019-05-17T19:09:57.944+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to mongotest1:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest1:27017 with a 5 second timeout)",
            "2019-05-17T19:09:57.945+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest5:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest5:27017 with a 5 second timeout)",
            "mongotest1:27017",
            "2019-05-17T19:09:57.949+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest3:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest3:27017 with a 5 second timeout)",
            "2019-05-17T19:09:57.951+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to mongotest4:27017 (1 connections now open to mongotest4:27017 with a 5 second timeout)"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get the first line of stdout_lines that does not match the timestamp prefix pattern "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}[+-][0-9]{4}\s+" and store the result in a variable.  The first, and only, result should be the line "mongotest1:27017".  How can I do this?

Additionally, is there some other way to get the MongoDB primary without using the mongo shell so I don't encounter these problems with the shell output?

Comment: This is the link to the existing MongoDB bug regarding the information messages https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27159

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for this.

I created a new filter task that checks for the inverse of the time stamp prefix:

```
- name: filter unwanted informational messages from primary result
  set_fact:
    filtered_lines: "{{ primary_result.stdout_lines | select('match', '^(?!([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}[+-][0-9]{4}\\s+))') | list }}"
  run_once: true
```

I then set a fact using the first list item in the filtered_lines result

```
- name: set primary host:port string
  set_fact:
    primary: "{{ filtered_lines[0] }}"
  run_once: true
```

This seems to be working in testing